# Spoofing messages for a Legal Company

Tags: sms, messaging, smslib

We have application that automatically sends message through a broadband stick then We want to buy a sim or any other way (LEGALLY) that make our Sender number will be a Company name

0999xxxxxx7 into CompanyName

please give me suggestion

(Philippines)

Comment: Please share what you have tried  so far and then explain  exact issue, then someone will be able to  help you. Refer this link for [asking proper questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like http://www.clickatell.com/ and specify the sender ID when sending messages through their API. However, the sender ID capability is not supported everywhere and you might have to get multiple numbers from then to support different locations.